# error occured when redirect blade file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

need redirect to collaborates blade file after form data saving in projectcontroller

```
 $project->save();

        return redirect()->route('projects.collaborators')->with('info','Your Project has been created successfully');
    }
```

routes is this

```
Route::get('/collaborators', function(){
    return view('projects.collaborators');
});
```

collaborators blade file is in projects folder in view file.

but occured this error message

> Route [projects.collaborators] not defined.

how to fix this problem

Comment: Do you have any route with the name of `projects.collaborators`

Comment: how can I create a method in My contoller and view this blade file?

Answer (score 0):

You have a route for `collaboratos`, so

```
return redirect()->route('projects.collaborators')->with('info','Your Project has been created successfully');
```

should be

```
return redirect()->route('collaboratos')->with('info','Your Project has been created successfully');
```

`route()` should have the routes that you define in `web.php`. Instead of route name, you have provided view which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
return redirect(url('/collaborators'))->with('info','Your Project has been created successfully');
```